# Can add own voice to TTS voice

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, text-to-speech, speech

There are some built-in sound in TTS(Text-to-speech) like sam at XP and ana for vista, is there any way to add own sound in it.

Comment: Are you looking to build a TTS voice based on your own voice, or simply add a 3rd party TTS voice?

Comment: I want to add my own TTS voice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit of research, and [this site](http://www.research-lab.com/ttsbuilder/help.htm) offers a toolkit to build your own TTS voice based on the (sapi-compatible) Festival TTS engine.  I can't make any comments on the voice quality.  The Microsoft TTS engines don't support user-generated voice construction.

There are other vendors out there (I seem to recall that AT&T Natural Voices supported user-generated voices), but most of them are *extremely* expensive (several tens of thousands of dollars).